# I can't send excel file from telegram bot in java. It works when i run program in my pc but on server it's not working

Tags: java, telegram-bot

if (text.equals("Excel fayl olish")){

```
  WriteToExcel writeToExcel = new WriteToExcel(timeRepository);
  writeToExcel.writeToFile();
  String path= "src/main/resources/XodimlarRo'yxati.xls";
  writeToExcel.writeToFile();
  sendDocument(chat_id, new File(path), "Xodimlar ro'yxati");
```

}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think , your path is wrong 
I sent file from server 
This is my file path: 
/root/projects/downloads/2022/10/30/jpg/58d08808-a29a-415f-8a9a-98a24019a165.jpg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).